# Does router push method refresh the page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In Vuejs vue-router package is do all the routing functions with ease,
it has `$router.push()` and `$router.go` methods my questions is does this two methods refresh the page when it's changin the page ?

Comment: No. With SPA routing in frontend frameworks like React or Vue, the URL is only changed for a *perceived* change in page, but no refreshes occur for faster and seamless transitions, there is no actual server-side routing happening. All just rerendering components internally.

Comment: so is there a way to do it ? with vue-router

Comment: why do you want a refresh

Comment: i have a login vue(with css style) when i log in and it directs to home page but its having same style which login page have, after refresh it does change.

Comment: Are you using scoped CSS?

Comment: it load component into router view

Comment: yeah i scoped it but it wont work. Only works after page refrsh

Comment: @C2486 but how ? i wrote style under style tag and scoped it to login component only.

Comment: You should use a store (Vuex) and keep logged-in user data there, it will be accessible across whole app and all components which are using `currentUser` (or w/e you name it) store property will have it updated once it changes.

Comment: @dziraf , i already done it , thing is some changes wont show until refresh the page.

Comment: Then it depends what your changes are, if you add or delete a new property inside your object, Vue may not detect it and you may want to use `Vue.set`:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: @dziraf thanks i'll try.